# In an assignment A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same

Tags: matlab, variable-assignment

```
    if (hidden_layer>1)
        for i =1 :hidden_layer 
       start_hidden_layer(i) = rand([gk(i+1),(gk(i)+1)])-0.5 ; 
        end
    end
```

hi Friends. 
I know every iteration was changed start_hidden_layer matrix dimensional.But all start_hidden_layer values must saved. How to solve this problem?

firstly hidden_layer>1

gk(i) is integer value for example 5 , 3, 8

Comment: For a good question the code snippet must make sense. The simplest way to do this is to define sample values for all variables used in the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're calling `rand` with different matrix sizes on each iteration, you cannot save the results into a normal matrix. You need to use a cell matrix to store the result, like this:

```
%//preallocate the cell array
start_hidden_layer = cell(1, hidden_layer);

for i = 1:hidden_layer
    start_hidden_layer{i} = rand([gk(i+1), (gk(i)+1)]) - 0.5; 
end
```

For more on cell arrays and how to use them, see [this Mathworks help doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html).

Comment: Thanks for answer. but  if ı call start_hidden_layer cell ; how ı can use matris values ?   Ans  : I find it. i = 1 , 2 .. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Adrian Cell matrices are both similar and different from normal numeric matrices. Whereas numeric matrices translate well to those found in linear algebra, cell matrices are more tied to the programming concept of multi-dimensional arrays. A simple way to view them is to think them as baskets that can hold anything: integers, matrices, structures, objects ...etc. See [this article](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) on how to work with cell data.